# axios typeError: Cannot set property 'username' of undefined

Tags: vue.js, axios

When I used POSTMAN to test the backend API, everything went right and the response data looked like:
`{"username":"123","email":"123@gmail.com"}`. Then I used axios to get the data:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Welcome!</h1>
        <div>
            <b-button @click="getInfo()">Get your information</b-button>
            <h2 v-if="username !== ''">Your username is: {{ username }}</h2>
            <h2 v-if="email !== ''">Your email is: {{ email }}</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
    data () {
        return {
            username: '',
            email: ''
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getInfo () {
            axios.get('http://localhost:8088/api/information')
            .then(function (response) {
                this.username = response.data['username'];
                this.email = response.data['email'];
                console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

But there was an error `typeError: Cannot set property 'username' of undefined`. I am confused about it. Could anyone help?

Comment: I got it. It the `this` thing. `this` in `this.username = response.data['username'];` doesn't point to Vue intstance but `undefined.` Use arrow function instead of `function (response) { //... }` .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: Unless you're using transpilers, arrow functions will give problems to older browsers or shittier ones *cough* ie11 *cough*. It's safer to just declare `this` on a variable at the top of the method and use that variable instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use the `arrow function in es6 instead of function ()` in here,

example: `(response)=>{`   instead of `function(response){`

```
methods: {
      getInfo () {
          axios.get('http://localhost:8088/api/information')
          .then((response)=> {
              this.username = response.data['username'];
              this.email = response.data['email'];
              console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
              console.log(error);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: if you look the official doc (https://github.com/axios/axios) it uses a normal anonymous function. so this is not the reason.